# Maximum Likelihood for multivariable non-linear normal distrubution

Tags: r, mle

I am trying to write a code to determine g, sigma and lambda using maximum likelihood for the following 
[Function Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zWsW.png). I have needed to restrict the intervals to ensure that the equation is not taking the log of a negative number, however, it is coming up with the error "L-BFGS-B needs finite values". What can I do to fix this?

```
lnQs<- c(0.4452211,  3.2828926,  3.0752400,  2.6613305,  5.8122312,  0.5629881,  0.8445112,  4.4336806,  3.8253957,  0.9336889,  1.5188934,  4.3915304, 2.5368227,  0.3729370,  2.3683679,  2.3555777,  0.5985054,  0.6240360,  0.9462143,  0.5440311,  2.6390102,  0.4921728,  0.2971820,  0.1939826, 0.5621709,  0.7839881,  2.2367834, 10.4101839,  5.8010886,  6.0974008)
Rf<- c(0.0484, 0.0537, 0.0598, 0.0590, 0.0590, 0.0571, 0.0497, 0.0497, 0.0492, 0.0588, 0.0586, 0.0492, 0.0468, 0.0480, 0.0405, 0.0405, 0.0488, 0.0452, 0.0675, 0.0395, 0.0395, 0.0385, 0.0400, 0.0432, 0.0394, 0.0397, 0.0397, 0.0407, 0.0436, 0.0436)
S<- c(0.8,  2.3,  2.2,  3.3,  4.9,  8.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1.8,  2.3,  1.3,  1.9,  5.7,  9.3,  4.9, 18.7,  3.6,  2.4, 15.1, 10.3,  0.8,  2.9, 12.0,  0.8,  9.9,  1.3,  8.9, 12.3,  4.2,  4.2)
T<- c(1.0,  5.0,  5.0,  7.0,  5.1, 21.0, 14.1,  5.0,  5.0, 12.0,  7.0,  3.0,  7.0, 21.0,  7.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 20.0,  5.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.1, 21.0, 14.0,  12.0, 14.0,  5.0,  5.0)

LL<- function(g,sigma,lambda){
  R=(dnorm(lnQs,(log(1+Rf+lambda)-sigma^2/2)*S-log(((1+Rf+lambda)/(1+g))^T-1),sigma*S^0.5))
#
    -sum(log(R), log=TRUE)
}
fit<-mle(minuslogl=LL, start=list(g=.05, sigma=.2, lambda=.1), method = "L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0,0,0.0915),upper=c(0.13,Inf,Inf))
summary(fit)
#Criteria required 
#   lambda>-(1+Rf)  - easily done with restriction lambda>0
#   lambda>(g-Rf)   - NOT SURE HOW TO DEAL WITH lowest Rf=0.0385, tried putting upper limit on g and lower limit on lambda for now
#   sigma>0         - easily done with restriction sigma>0
#   Problem that L-BFGS-B needs finite values offit<-mle(minuslogl=LL, start=list(g=.077, sigma=.256, lambda=.110), method = "BFGS")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the Inf limits for your sigma and lambda parameters for MLE? for example the following works without error (although the lambda estimate is pretty bad with high std error):

```
set.seed(123)
T<-0.5
S<-1
Rf<-2
g <-.1 
sigma <- .5
lambda <- 1
lnQs <- rnorm(100,(log(1+Rf+lambda)-sigma^2/2)*S-log(((1+Rf+lambda)/(1+g))^T-1),sigma*S^0.5)

# negative ll fn  
LL<- function(g,sigma,lambda){
  R <- dnorm(lnQs,(log(1+Rf+lambda)-sigma^2/2)*S-log(((1+Rf+lambda)/(1+g))^T-1),sigma*S^0.5)
  -sum(log(R))
}
fit<-mle(minuslogl=LL, start=list(g=.05, sigma=.2, lambda=.1), method = "L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0,0,0.0915),upper=c(0.13,5,5))
summary(fit)
Maximum likelihood estimation

Call:
mle(minuslogl = LL, start = list(g = 0.05, sigma = 0.2, lambda = 0.1), 
    method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0, 0, 0.0915), upper = c(0.13, 
        5, 5))

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error
g       0.10583  16.869598
sigma   0.45412   0.032111
lambda  0.39076 363.867321
```

With the data you provided, the LL evaluates to infinity at many points with many different values of your parameters, for example using a simple grid search on [0,1]x[0,1]x[0,1] you can find the following points where LL evaluates to infinity (and sometimes NAN too), that's why L-BFGS-G fails:

```
g <- seq(0,1,length=10)
sigma <- seq(0,1,length=10)
lambda <- seq(0,1,length=10)
# grid search
for (i in 1:10) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    for (k in 1:10) {
      if (LL(g[i],sigma[j],lambda[k]) == Inf) {
        print(paste(g[i],sigma[j],lambda[k]))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some points where LL evaluates to Inf

```
[1] "0 0 0"
[1] "0 0 0.111111111111111"
[1] "0 0 0.222222222222222"
[1] "0 0 0.333333333333333"
[1] "0 0 0.444444444444444"
[1] "0 0 0.555555555555556"
[1] "0 0 0.666666666666667"
[1] "0 0 0.777777777777778"
[1] "0 0 0.888888888888889"
[1] "0 0 1"
[1] "0 0.111111111111111 0.111111111111111"
[1] "0 0.111111111111111 0.222222222222222"
[1] "0 0.111111111111111 0.333333333333333"
[1] "0 0.111111111111111 0.444444444444444"
```

There is a simple hack that may fix the problem:

```
LL<- function(g,sigma,lambda){
      R=(dnorm(lnQs,(log(1+Rf+lambda)-sigma^2/2)*S-log(((1+Rf+lambda)/(1+g))^T-1),sigma*S^0.5))
      #
      ll <- -sum(log(R), log=TRUE)
      ifelse(ll == Inf, 9999999, ll) # return a large enough number if Inf
}

fit<-mle(minuslogl=LL, start=list(g=.05, sigma=.2, lambda=.1), method = "L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0,0,0.0915),upper=c(0.13,Inf,Inf))
summary(fit)


Maximum likelihood estimation

Call:
mle(minuslogl = LL, start = list(g = 0.05, sigma = 0.2, lambda = 0.1), 
    method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0, 0, 0.0915), upper = c(0.13, 
        Inf, Inf))

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error
g      0.1249300 0.07295480
sigma  0.8795551 0.07349924
lambda 0.0915000 0.07459289

-2 log L: 160.1491
```

Comment: When I replace the upper limits with 5's it still comes up with the error "L-BFGS-B needs finite values of

Comment: here is the data for T, S, Rf and lnQs if that helps:

Comment: just used a hack to fix the issue with L-BFGS-B, whenever LL evaluates to infinity return a large enough number from LL function and it seems to work. Let's see if it fits your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually have optimal results and just learning how to get to them. They are: g=0.077 (0.028), lambda=0.110 (0.032) and sigma=0.256 (0.033). Do you have any idea what would cause this discrepancy?

Comment: tried with BGFS and CG methods too, getting similar solutions with you data. My hunch is probably it's getting stuck into local minima

Comment: I have tried changing the start conditions to the actual answers provided in lectures, however it still moves away from these points. This indicates to me that there is something else wrong

Comment: I have to go with what I have as don't have time to keep going with this. One last (slightly related) question is to do with calculating the correlation between g and lambda. Would you have any idea how to do that?